# read/write from socket unexpected behavior

Tags: c, sockets

I have an assignment which I have to download a file from the server .. but I have this thing that sometimes the data is send and sometimes they just not !!

server :

```
printf("Reading and sending the File.\n");
memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
while((n=read(fp, buff, 1024)) > 0 )
{   
    printf ("%s \n", buff); //no problem, coz it reads the file correctly  
    write(connfd, buff, n); 
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
}
```

client:

```
printf("Start downloading the file.\n");
bzero(&data,sizeof(data));
n = 0;
while (1)
{
    n = read(sockfd , data, 1024);
    if (n > 0)
    {
         data[n] = 0;
         r = write (fp, data, n);
         if (r < 0)
         {
             printf("Write to file !!!!!!\n");
         exit(1);
         }
    }
    printf ("\n%s\n", data);
    bzero (&data, sizeof (data));
    if (n < 1024)
        break;
}
printf("Done downloading the file\n");
close (fp);
```

Comment: `printf ("%s \n", buff);` should causes undefined behavior because read doesn't give nul terminated string. and you are using `%s`. So probability your code is working for small file < 1024 bytes

Comment: On the server side do you close the connection after use?

Comment: @BogdanM yes I close it

Comment: have you tried to flush the file with fflush()?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan even if I remove it the problem is still there !! I just try it the first and second time it sends the third it dosen't !!!

Comment: You should read until you get EOF. You may recv smaller chunks than 1024 if the reader is faster than the network.

Comment: @Mi_hopeso there must be some other error that I have not encounter (but using printf with `%s` was wrong remove that). What do you mean by third time?

Comment: @Mi_hopeso Does loop breaks or client code hangs?

Comment: @t7bdh3hdhb no I didn't use it but isn't the bzero enough to clean the buffers ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan the loop breaks, and I mean the third run

Comment: @Mi_hopeso Is any error thrown at those times when no data is sent? Also, is that all the code or there's something else in it?

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD no errors, and this is not the whole code but the other parts I've already checked them

Answer (score 1):

Because of implementation reasons (socket, TCP stack, ethernet stack, ...) you may not always get 1024 bytes in each read even if this many were sent.

You are using `if (n < 1024)` to check if you are done. This should not be done with sockets.

First you need to change `read` to `recv` which is specifically designed to work with sockets. `recv` will return `0` if the server has performed an orderly shutdown of the connection and `-1` if an error occurred. Any other return value means: continue reading!

```
printf("Start downloading the file.\n");
ssize_t n;
while (1)
{
    n = recv(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0);
    if (n > 0)
    {
         r = write (fp, data, n);
         if (r < 0)
         {
            perror("write");
            exit(1);
         }

        printf ("\n%*s\n", n, data);
    }
    else if (!n)
        break; // orderly shutdown
    else {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
}
printf("Done downloading the file\n");
close (fp);
```

Comment: if the server does not call explicitly `close` or `shutdown`, there is not difference between checking for < 1024 or zero.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that client receives less data than 1024, but that is not the last block of data sent. This may be cause by the condition of the link channel. Your code does not take into account this situation as if the data read from the socket is less than 1024, the while is terminated by the break instruction. As result, the remaining data (which is correctly sent) is lost in the client side.

To improve you file transfer system, I would suggest to send the size of the files as first information and then use the file size to verify when a file in entirely received.

Another option could be to use the [sendfile](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) system call, which is optimized for this kind of operation.

Comment: but before I check if the data is less than 1024 and break from the loop, I write it to the file !!

Comment: if ( n < 1024) is not the correct condition to verify when the entire file has been entirely sent.

Comment: the thing that I want to do do is to send 1024 bytes at a time, so when this condition is true that's mean I get to the end of the file !

Comment: yes, you can do that. But there is not guarantee that you will receive them in blocks of 1024 bytes.